# What is the C-API interface to create built-in array object in Python?

Tags: python, c, multidimensional-array, python-extensions, memoryview

I am working on a Python C-extension code. Currently, a 1D C-array is converted to a Python List. Now I need to convert an ND-array, described by a 1) data type, 2) shape (as a 1D integer vector, for example, 2x4x3 array), and 3) data binary payload as serialized array elements of data-type.

I noticed that there is an `array` object in python: https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html

I prefer to convert the ND array buffer to an `array` object instead of requiring installation of `numpy` ndarray - an additional dependency, but I failed to find any C-API to create/read/write Python-`array` objects from C.

does this interface (something similar to `PyList_New`) exist?

Comment: The Python `array` class is not multi-dimensional.  But for interface the class offers a `buffer protocol`.  Also switch to Py3 if you can.  If you don't want to use `numpy`, why the [numpy] tag?

Comment: I found the buffer object API, which supports shapes (ND) and data types: https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/buffer.html#the-new-style-py-buffer-struct is a buffer object good for this purpose?

Comment: I haven't used it so can't help.  BUT, what do you intend to do with these 'arrays' in Python.  Without `numpy` or `PIL` it doesn't look like you can do much; at least I'm not aware of any builtin packages that use attributes like shape and strides.

Comment: You should almost certainly use either nested lists or NumPy. `array.array` arrays will be useless to you, and the buffer API is mostly useful for C-level access, not for providing a Python interface.

Comment: is there a convenient/short way to create multi-dimensional list? the data loading may have various dimensions , 3D, or 4D, a nested loop is a bit cumbersome? alternatively, a list reshape function in C-API would also solve this problem. this is in C.

Comment: if I switch to numpy C-APIs, I assume a user of the module must pre-install numpy, correct?